# Problemas com três forms e picture box

Tags: c#, thread, picturebox

Oi, o meu cenário é o seguinte:
- Formulário de configuração (nome, e-mail e uma foto)
- Formulário ABC - que possui um formulário que é aberto ao clicar num Button do formulário ABC
- Formulário BCA - que possui um formulário que é aberto ao clicar num Button do formulário BCA

O formulário ABC ou o formulário BCA serão chamados com base da escolha feita no formulário de Configuração, através de radio buttons.

Nesse formulário de configuração também é feita a escolha de uma imagem jpg/png que o usuário vai procurar no próprio pc. Depois de todos os dados preenchidos e foto escolhida nesse formulário de configuração, o usuário clicará num botão "Iniciar", onde com base da escolha do ratio button ABC ou BCA vai abrir seus respectivos formulários. E também, a imagem será salva numa pasta com o nome de logo.jpg.

No formulário ABC ou formulário BCA também há uma picture box onde será carregado a imagem salva na pasta X (C:\X\Img\logo.jpg). Aí que entra o meu problema. Ambos formulário ABC ou BCA tem um botão que leva em outro formulário, onde também será carregado a mesma picture box... Porém dispara um erro, pois diz que a imagem já está carregada.

Observação: Pra 'finalizar' o form de configuração eu uso this.Visible = false;
E também para os formulários ABC e BCA. Creio que é por isso que dá esse erro, pois a imagem já está com um espaço alocado na memória..

Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

```
private void pictureBox_logo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
 file.Filter = "PNG|* .png|BMP|*.bmp|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg";
 if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
 pictureBox_logo.ImageLocation = file.FileName
}
 pictureBox_logo.Image.Save(@"C\tools\img\logo.jpg");

}
```

E no outro form (que será aberto com a escolha do radio button ABC ou BCA)

```
public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
 {
    public frmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        picturebox_principal.Load(@"C:\tools\img\logo.jpg");
     }
}
```

Comment: Sem o código onde o erro ocorre fica difícil, poste o código.

Comment: Pronto editei... Espero que dê pra entender...
No que eu havia escrito dá pra entender um pouco melhor o meu cenário... A imagem é carregada num formulário, quando tento abrir outro formulário através de um botão e carregar a mesma imagem, dispara um erro falando que a imagem já está em uso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o código disponibilizado não há em nenhum momento a atribuição da imagem para o componente PictureBox, logo ao executar a linha que tem o .Save() ocorre erro de referência nula.

Segue código modificado:

```
using (OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
     openDialog.Filter = "PNG|* .png|BMP|*.bmp|JPG|*.jpg;*.jpeg";
     if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openDialog.FileName);

     pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"C:\tools\img\ip.png");
}
```

O carregamento da imagem no outro PictureBox será feito da mesma forma:

```
public Form2()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      pictureBox2.Load(@"C:\tools\img\ip.png");
}
```